# Moving multiple files in subdirectories (and/or splitting strings by multichar delimeter) [bash]

Tags: bash, split, mv

So basically, I have a folder with a bunch of subfolders all with over 100 files in them. I want to take all of the mp3 files (really generic extension since I'll have to do this with jpg, etc.) and move them to a new folder in the original directory. So basically the file structure looks like this:

> /.../dir/recup1/file1.mp3
>
> /.../dir/recup2/file2.mp3
>
> ... etc.

and I want it to look like this:

> /.../dir/music/file1.mp3
>
> /.../dir/music/file2.mp3
>
> ... etc.

I figured I would use a bash script that looked along these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
STR=`find ./ -type f -name \*.mp3`

FILES=(echo $STR | tr ".mp3 " "\n")

for x in $FILES
do
    echo "> [$x]"
done
```

I just have it echo for now, but eventually I would want to use `mv` to get it to the correct folder. Obviously this doesn't work though because tr sees each character as a delimiter, so if you guys have a better idea I'd appreciate it.

(FYI, I'm running netbook Ubuntu, so if there's a GUI way akin to Windows' search, I would not be against using it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `music` folder exists then the following should work -

```
find /path/to/search -type f -iname "*.mp3" -exec mv {} path/to/music \;
```

A `-exec command` must be terminated with a `;` (so you usually need to type `\;` or `';'` to avoid interpretion by the shell) or a `+`. The difference is that with `;`, the command is called once per file, with `+`, it is called just as few times as possible (usually once, but there is a maximum length for a command line, so it might be split up) with all filenames.

Comment: What's the final `\;` for? Edit: Nevermind, the guy below answers it.

Comment: Updated the answer with the explaination. Hope that helps!

Comment: You may use `+` instead of the `\;`, it will be much faster. Most modern `find` implementations support it.

Comment: How do I exclude the music file from the search? Would I just include `--exclude=./music` after the `-type f`?

Comment: Also, how do I use the + implementation? (If it wasn't clear already, I'm not too familiar with bash syntax.) I tried `find ./ -type f -iname "*.mp3" -exec cp {} ./temp +`, but was greeted with the error `find: missing argument to '-exec'`. Thanks for all your help by the way!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
find /some/dir -type f -iname '*.mp3' -exec mv \{\} /where/to/move/ \;
```

The `\{\}` part will be replaced by the found file name/path. The `\;` part sets the end for the `-exec` part, it can't be left out.

If you want to print what was found, just add a `-print` flag like:

```
find /some/dir -type f -iname '*.mp3' -print -exec mv \{\} /where/to/move/ \;
```

HTH