# Removing a level in a file structure with Bash while preserving files

Tags: bash, ubuntu, filesystems, find, mv

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

I have a situation where I have a DIR that contains several dozen sub DIRs, where all of the sub DIRs contain only one file (for some errant reason). I'm trying to move all of the files up two levels in the DIR tree while preserving the file structure in all other ways. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
|--- DIR.Main
|--- |---DIR.Sub-A
|--- |--- |--- File.Sub-A
|--- |---DIR.Sub-B
|--- |--- |--- File.Sub-B
|--- |---DIR.Sub-C
|--- |--- |--- File.Sub-C
|-->Continue for approx. 50 DIR.Subs
```

I do not need the DIR.Sub level in the file structure, and would like it to look like this instead:

```
|--- DIR.Main
|--- |---File.Sub-A
|--- |---File.Sub-B
|--- |---File.Sub-C
```

Here's what's compounding problem, though: The file names aren't neatly and logically ordered as in the previous example but rather are named haphazardly like this:

```
|--- DIR.Main
|--- |---DIR.Sasjaljesea
|--- |--- |--- File.Sasjalsaejesea.mpg
|--- |---DIR.qwerqwerewqwer
|--- |--- |--- File.qwerqweresezswqwer.mpg
|--- |---DIR.xcbxcvxcvbxcvb
|--- |--- |--- File.xcsfasdbxcvxcvbxcvb.mpg
|-->ETC
```

However, a saving grace is that as in the above example, all of the files share the same file type (mpg, in this case).

I've read the documentation for mv and for cp in Bash and have not been able to come up with a way to do this in one pass without typing all of the file names manually. I've also explored options with Xrandr and similar commands. The closest I've been able to come to a solution is this:

```
find /path/to/search -type f -iname "*.mp3" -exec mv {} path/to/music \;
```

Taken from this answer: [Moving multiple files in subdirectories (and/or splitting strings by multichar delimeter) [bash]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705757/moving-multiple-files-in-subdirectories-and-or-splitting-strings-by-multichar-d)

Where I obviously corrected the -iname to .mpg and the DIRs to fit my situation.

When I did this it did find all of files and moved them to the folder I wanted but it concatenated all of the files into one unreadable .mpg file instead of recursively copying each individual file and maintaining the file structure as I wanted. I have researched using cp recursively in the above command in place of of mv but this seemed to do nothing, even when I executed as SUDO. cp comes with the additional problem that I don't WANT to duplicate the files, simply delete the intermediary folder in which they are contained.

You've probably figured out that I'm trying to avoid simply using the GUI in Linux and go the Bash route for the obvious reason that it would take hours to do this in the window manager whereas I'm sure there is a way to do it in Bash in seconds. This is a task that would normally take a few seconds in the Linux File Manager as well if one were dealing with less than a dozen folders and files to move, but the current situation is that there are dozens upon dozens of unnecessary DIRs wrapping just one file. Hence, I need a good clean Bash solution.

Thank you again for your help. This is a problem that's been frustrating me for weeks.

I welcome any questions.

Comment: a model question for file operations, especially the `DIR ...` graph. Keep posting and good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xargs` used with `mv` can solve this. You should start with current working directory of `DIR.Main`, and with a different directory to move everything to. It needs to be different because otherwise you'll end up with the (empty) original directories intersperced with your new files and directories. We could get around this, but I don't think there's any need.

```
find -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 | xargs -I '{}' mv '{}' <PATH_TO_NEW_LOCATION>/
```

The `find` result is a list of all files and directories that are exactly one layer further into the directory tree than the current directory. The `xargs` call then moves all of these results into the location given.

I have tested it, but you might like to test it too before you use it on your live data, or at least take a copy.

Comment: For some reason I had to give full permission to "Others" (create and delete files), otherwise I got a "Cannot move file EXAMPLE, permission denied." - even when I ran as SUDO. I'm not sure why this is, but once I gave the new permissions this solved my problem. Thank you so very much.

Comment: If you put `sudo` in front of this command then it will only apply up to the `find` command, and not to the `xargs` command which is actually doing the moving. Glad you got it working though.

Answer (score 0):

This should be just as simple as

```
shopt -s dotglob; mv -iv DIR.Main/*/* DIR.Main/
```

If you hit `ARG_MAX` put it in a loop

```
shopt -s dotglob; for f in DIR.Main/*/*; do mv -iv "$f" DIR.Main/
```